# Accessing global variables from inside a loop with Assemble

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, gruntjs, assemble

using Grunt.js 0.4 and [Assemble 0.3.78](https://github.com/assemble/assemble)

how can I access 'page.filename' global variable from inside a loop?

(debug)

```
<ul>
  {{#mysite.menu}}
    <li>{{page.filename}}</li>
  {{/mysite.menu}}
</ul>
```

(actually)
building a menu, trying this:

```
{{#mysite.menu}}
  <li {{#is page.filename url}} class="on" {{/is}}>{{name}}</li>
{{/mysite.menu}}
```

where `url` and `name` are attributes of each `mysite.menu`

Comment: this is handlebars-related, not grunt

Comment: Incorrect. It's assemble related, since it's referring to a pre-defined variable, page.filename, which is a feature of Assemble - a Grunt.js plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would help to have a little more information than what you provided, like an example of the data you're using. But I'll try to answer if I can. To clarify, `page` and `filename` are both built-in "helpers"/variables in Assemble, `filename` is one of several "path" helpers, here are some others:

- **dirname**: Returns the absolute path to the given file/directory. Would return: `path/to/variables.md`. Usage: `{{dirname [path]}}`
- **pagename**: Returns the full-name of a given file. Would return: `variables.md`. Usage: `{{filename "docs/toc.md"}}`
- **filename**: Can be used as an alternate for `pagename`.
- **basename**: Returns the basename of a given file. Would return: `variables` Usage: `{{base "docs/toc.md"}}`
- **extension**: Returns the extension of a given file. Would return: `.md` Usage: `{{extension "docs/toc.md"}}`
- **ext**: Can be used as an alternate for`extension`.
- **relative**: Returns the derived relative path from file A to file B. Usage: `{{relative [from] [to]}}`.

These can be used with `page` like this:

```
{{page.dest}}
{{page.absolute}}
{{page.dirname}}
{{page.filename}}
{{page.pagename}}
{{page.basename}}
{{page.extname}}
{{page.ext}}
```

or, depending on context and what you need:

```
{{this.dest}}
{{this.dirname}}
{{this.filename}}
{{this.pagename}}
{{this.basename}}
{{this.extname}}
{{this.ext}}
```

When you use the templates inside of `{{#each}}` blocks like in your example, you will need to add `../` to go up a level of context:

```
{{../page.dest}}
{{../page.absolute}}
{{../page.dirname}}
{{../page.filename}}
{{../page.pagename}}
{{../page.basename}}
{{../page.extname}}
{{../page.ext}}
```

or, again depending on what else is on your page. (I have no idea how much nesting is going on in the rest of the templates, etc.)

```
{{../dest}}
{{../absolute}}
{{../dirname}}
{{../filename}}
{{../pagename}}
{{../basename}}
{{../extname}}
{{../ext}}
```

My recommendation is that you just copy/paste all of the templates I listed into a page and build it. Then look at the results and see which templates are working and it should help you start wrapping your brain around how the templates are working. Context with Handlebars is confusing at first, but hopefully this will help.

Also, if you're still having trouble after that maybe take a look at some of the "assemble-examples" repos and try to get your templates/pages building first *without* any of these helpers. Then commit your work and introduce the helpers, **but not just one or two helpers at a time**, when I was learning I started adding dozens of helpers to a page just to speed up the process of seeing what happened in the output, what broke, look at diffs to see what changed. etc.

Let me know if this at least gets you somewhere. I'm happy to keep helping.

Comment: BTW, full disclosure - if it wasn't obvious I'm on the assemble team. And @Rui I would update Assemble to 0.3.79. I made updates to some of these helpers right before you posted your question

Comment: great answer Jon, I have it working now.. I was missing the Handlebars context concept, here's the new code: <li {{#is ../page.filename url}} class="on" {{/is}}>{{name}}</li>

Comment: great! let me know if you need more help. we've been having a lot of fun with assemble :-)

Comment: Btw, for your <li>, since you have a template for a URL, wouldn't you want to do this (or something like it): <li class="on"><a href="{{#is ../page.filename url}}{{/is}}">{{name}}</a> </li>, with the template inside the `href`? Be sure to look at `{{assets}}` and `{{relative}}` as well. Those will be handy

Comment: i didn't want to bug people with my detailed code.. i just pasted here illustrative code to what I wanted to achieve.. thanks a bunch, Jon. The actual code is: <li><a href="{{{url}}}" {{#is ../page.basename url}} class="on" {{/is}}>{{{name}}}</a></li>  Assemble rocks, i'm building my site using Grunt watch Sass pre-processing and Assemble static html. I will share its code here on github as it will be hosted with GitHub pages, i'll let you know :)

Comment: That's great to hear, there is a lot that Assemble does that I haven't had time to document, so please do ask questions if you have them. at the risk of exposing my how nerdy I really am, I love doing stuff with assemble, so answering questions is not a problem.

Comment: thanks, sure will. Maybe I can help, too.. Assemble deserves it's own homepage :)

Comment: that would be great :-) Let me know if you want to get more involved, I have lots of documentation to push up